Autodesk reality capture api getting fail in last step of processing 3D model.......Getting Error "Specified file ID doesn't exist"
`I am trying to generated 3D model from 2D images using Autodesk Reality Capture API and following this tutorial link :
https://aps.autodesk.com/developer/learn/recap-app/overview
My images uploading successfully but at the last step of processing, after sometime I am always getting this error "Specified file ID doesn't exist".......not sure what I am missing
Following is the code that I am using to upload and process image:
click to see code
Please help me to resolve this issue
I tried following this tutorial link :
https://aps.autodesk.com/developer/learn/recap-app/overview`

Do NOT put the code in an image file if you expect answers!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Most probably there is an error processing your photoscene and consequently, when trying to access the results, it cannot find the resulted file.
I looked at the code from your image and I think the problem is that you are using only 4 images.
Please check The Hitchhiker's Guide to ... Reality Capture API) that should also provide some insights on minimum number of images needed to get (at least) a result.
